# Traceback of exceptions: Upper frames missing

Tags: python, exception, tornado

In the following stacktrace I miss the upper frames.

Who called callback() in ioloop.py line 458?

The stacktrace comes from a unittest TestCase. All tests pass but this traceback is in the logs and reproducible.

I can't see in which test of the TestCase the exception was raised.

```
ERROR    [25950] Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x5358368>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 458, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
    raise_exc_info(exc)
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/src/websocketrpc/websocketrpc/client.py", line 71, in connect
    self.ws = websocket_connect(self.args.url)
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/src/websocketrpc/websocketrpc/client.py", line 179, in websocket_connect
    conn = websocket.WebSocketClientConnection(io_loop, request)
  File "/home/modwork_foo_dtg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 777, in __init__
    raise Exception('%s %s' % (request, request.url))
Exception: <tornado.httpclient._RequestProxy object at 0x535cb10> None
```

How could I use tornado to see the upper stacktrace frames?

The exception itself is not the problem.

Comment: Nice blog explaining why the upper frames are missing: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/03/generating-full-stack-traces-for.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IOLoop.handle_callback_exception`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#debugging-and-error-handling) to print from `sys.exc_info` to see what specifically is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The callback was invoked by ioloop.py:458, just like it says.  No outer stack frames are shown because the exception didn't escape that frame.  The thing that's confusing you is that the callback goes on to re-raise an exception that was captured earlier.

In Python 2, preserving tracebacks to re-raise later is messy (it gets better in Python 3).  Tornado usually does the right thing here, but there are some gaps where a traceback will get truncated.  The main problem I'm aware of in current versions is that AsyncHTTPClient tends to throw away tracebacks (and there are some annoying backwards-compatibility issues with fixing this).

As a crude workaround while debugging, you can try printing traceback.format_stack just before throwing an exception (at least where it's feasible to modify the code, as you've done here to add an exception to websocket.py).